# Printing a footer background that extends to the edge of the page

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, margins, footers

I have a [letterhead](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nd7evceyyhrrqcz/Letterhead.docx?dl=0) that was designed in Word. When I attempt to print the letterhead on US Letter paper (or A4, for that matter), the footer background does not extend to the edge of the page, as shown in this [screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/l/AdzELTcBccVCKa2o9oBtOk2ldQHqlLA2emM). What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: It may very well be that your printer cannot print to that edge.

Comment: Your first link is broken.

Comment: I believe Xavierjazz is right.  You have a few options: 1) Print it with a printer that prints to the edges (typically a feature of photo printers).  2) Trim the edges.  You may be able to find paper with micro-perf tear-off edges.  3) Cheapest solution: have a commercial printer pre-print the artwork.  It's much cheaper than doing it on a home printer (in quantity, not much more than the cost of the paper).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Xavierjazz, some printers do not support printing to the edge, probably like those low-budget ink-jet printers since I had one of them with the same issue, but that was in the days of Word XP. :)

However, try this to estimate if the problem is in the hardware or the software (I believe there are things that one of them could cause this). If you have Photoshop, try and produce your designs (the footer) and **print it from Photoshop** since it allows you to position the designs on the paper wherever you want. Using the `Photoshop Print Settings` dialogue box (`CTRL+P`), grouped under `Position and Size`, clear the tick mark of `Centre` and set the `Top:` and `Left:`. Click `Print`.

- If you succeeded, use the same paper you've just printed to print only the text in Word (remove the designs you've already printed). Apparently this is how you will do things, much like many people.
- If Photoshop didn't position the designs as you specified, there is no other tricks on your PC.

**Note:**

- If you don't have Photoshop but you have the designs saved as a printing-quality image, use alternatives like IrfanView that allows you to control where to print on the paper.